# Boolean alternating beetween different states without being updated

Tags: java

I have a Class called Node that, depending on the variable oddNode needs to have different functions called upon it, but upon debugging oddNode to the console, it alternates between true and false, printing truefalsetrue to the console. Any ideas of what this could be?

```
 boolean oddNode;
        network.add(new Node[dataIn.length]);
        for (int i = 1; i <= layers; i++) {

            int nLength = network.get(i - 1).length - 1;

            if (nLength % 2 == 0) {
                oddNode = false;
                network.add(new Node[nLength / 2]);
            } else {
                oddNode = true;
                network.add(new Node[(nLength - 1) / 2]);
            }
            Node[] currentLayer = network.get(i - 1);
            int cnLength = network.get(i).length - 1;
            System.out.println(oddNode);
            if (oddNode = false) {
                System.out.println("triggered first statement");
                for (int j = 1; j <= cnLength; j++) {
                    network.get(i)[j - 1].DualInputCalculation(currentLayer[j - 1], currentLayer[j]);
                }

            } else if(oddNode) {
                System.out.println("triggered second statement");
                network.get(i)[0].TripleInputCalculation(currentLayer[0], currentLayer[1], currentLayer[2]);
                for (int j = 4; j <= cnLength; j++) {
                    network.get(i)[j - 1].DualInputCalculation(currentLayer[j - 1], currentLayer[j]);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: `if (oddNode = false)` smells funny.

Comment: One `=` is assignment. `oddNode = false` is assigning `false` to `oddNode` (and evaluating to `false`). `if (!oddNode)` and `else`. Don't use an `else if` when there are only two possible conditions.

Comment: Can you show a runnable example please? The code you show here has neither a signature nor an actual call to your function.

Comment: Printing `truefalsetrue` because your `System.out.println(oddNode);`  inside for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple issue in 2nd if-else block and I assume that is a typo.

```
if (oddNode = false) {
    //
} else if(oddNode) {
    // 
}
```

In your if statement, instead of checking for the equality; the code is only doing a variable assignment.

```
oddNode = false // this assigns false value to oddNode
```

You need to change it as below.

```
if (oddNode == false) {
    //
} else if(oddNode) {
    // 
}
```

Also, as an additional improvement; you should try to avoid unwanted else-if statement here by replacing it as below.

```
if (oddNode == false) {
    //
} else {
    // If oddNode is not false; then it will always be true.
}
```

To make the code more readable, move the negate (false) to else.

```
if (oddNode) { // meaning oddNode == true
    // do the stuff when node is odd
} else {
    // do the stuff when node is even
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Victor Nordlinder: It is much more common and conventional to write the condition as `if (!oddNode) { ...` than the way you have written it, and the way it is written in this answer. It is best to follow the conventional style.

Comment: Also, even better, write the condition as `if (oddNode) { ...` and swap the order of the if- and then-branches.

Comment: @Lii - indeed, let me add that as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are printing the `oddNode` inside a `for` loop.
2. You have an `if...else` statement which is responsible for alternating your `oddNode`

This `if-else` block is performing the update

```
if (nLength % 2 == 0) {    
    oddNode = false;
    network.add(new Node[nLength / 2]);
} else {
    oddNode = true;
    network.add(new Node[(nLength - 1) / 2]);
}
```